# How do I go back to a square selector?

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools, select

My circle selector is locked, everytime I go back on my square selector and I click somewhere my circle selector comes back automatically. I don't know what to do I'm totally stuck. Even on a new file it does the same thing. (I have a Mac IDk if it useful to help me). Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: In the Tool panel, click on the first tool until you see the dropdown menu and select another one, or Shift Spacebar and do the same thing

Comment: I already tried that but everytime I select the square when I click on a object it goes automatically back to the circle selector.

Comment: Pressing 'W' should toggle through the selection options.

Comment: I've done it already but same probleme it always go back to the circle

Comment: did you try pressing ESC?